GCP PubSub with Cloud Functions => Aborted Requests
I'm pushing a fairly large number of small items (around 100k) into a PubSub queue. A cloud function then works on the tasks at hand. This setup leads me to the following error.

Does anyone know why I specifically run into this error? It doesn't make sense to me that GCP tries to scale to a point where it runs into an error It could simply work within its limits and take more time to complete the job. If not what's the point of separating the message producer and its consumers?
EDIT:
export const domainsScan = onMessagePublished(
  {
    topic: TopicNames.DomainScan,
    timeoutSeconds: 300,
    memory: '2GiB' as MemoryOption,
    region: FunctionConfig.Region
  } as PubSubOptions,
  async (event) => {

    logger.debug('Placeholder')

  }
)


The notion behind Cloud Functions is that you write the body of a function and Google takes care of triggering your code when a call/message is made/ready.  Cloud Functions has two implementations / generations knows as Gen1 and Gen2.  Gen2 is what you should be using and is the default and likely what you ARE using.  Cloud Functions Gen2, is actually built on top of Cloud Run.  As such, for best effect, you should also examine the Cloud Run documentation.
When we look at Cloud Run, we will find that it is based on Docker images.  When Cloud Functions runs, the Docker image is built for you and encapsulates your Cloud Function function code.
With this pre-amble, we can now get into the meat of the story and your issue.  When you configure a Cloud Run instance (implicitly done by Cloud Functions Gen2), there are two primary attributes relating to capacity.

Number of instances
Number of concurrent threads

The number of instances can be thought of as the number of compute instances that are available to you to run your work.  Think of these as VMs.  When a request arrives at Cloud Run to run some work, Cloud Run will spin up a VM (if one isn't already running) and then run your logic within that VM.  At the end of the run, the VM remains present ready to immediately handle the next request.  If no new request arrives in a period (15 minutes I believe) then VM goes away.  You are charged for the time spent while a request is being processed ... not for the VM startup and not for the idle time between requests.
When you configure Cloud Run, you get to specify the maximum number of instances you wish to allow.  When this number is reached, no new instances are created.  Requests to run work after that are either queued OR you may get an error similar to the one you listed .... i.e. no available instance.
I think we have now explained the core of the story.  You should check your Cloud Function configuration and its mapping to Cloud Run.  See how many instances you allowed and see how many were actually running when the error was encountered.
There is much more that can be said ... but I'll just briefly touch on concurrency.  Concurrency is the number of parallel requests that can be executed by ONE VM instance.  If the value of concurrency > 1 then that defines the number of concurrent requests that can be processed in a single VM instance.

Thanks for taking the time to answer, it goes into a lot of detail about the why my error happens. I still find it strange that with a PubSub I need to know how fast I want to process to avoid running into an error.

Let me suggest we update the question with the detailed definition of the PubSub subscription that causes the trigger of Cloud Functions / Cloud Run.  What I'm looking to see are the settings for the PubSub subscription retry ... see: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/retry-requests
What I'm thinking is that your PubSub subscription is likely "push" based ... meaning that a message will be pushed to Cloud Run.  If Cloud Run is configured for a maximum throughput (because of your cost constraints) ... then PubSub should/could retry until success.

I've updated the question so that it includes the actual functions definition.

What you updated with is the logic in your Cloud Funciton that HANDLES an incoming message being delivered from PubSub.  What I am looking for is the definition of your PubSub subscription.  This is not related to Cloud Functions.  Your PubSub subscription is the component that receives messages from the PubSub topic and then sends them (via REST) to your Cloud Function.

I'd need to dig it up - I ran into the problem using the standard Firebase PubSub mechanism.
